# Pandas boundary conditions problem when using apply on a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df` :

```
|            | Country     |    Pop1   |      Pop2 |  … |  Popn    |
|:-----------|------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:--:|:--------:|
| 0          |      Canada |     0     |     2     |  … |     50   |
| 1          |      China  |     0     |     5     |  … |     75   |
| 2          |     Croatia |     0     |     1     |  … |     30   |
```

For columns Pop1 until Popn, I want to substract the previous column values from the current. So I did this :

```py
df_copy = df.copy()
df_copy[df_copy.columns[2:]] = df_copy[df_copy.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(1), axis=1)
```

Yet, I encounter the following problem : my first column is Nan since there is no previous value.

```
|            | Country     |    Pop1   |      Pop2 |  … |  Popn    |
|:-----------|------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:--:|:--------:|
| 0          |      Canada |     Nan   |     2     |  … |     6    |
| 1          |      China  |     Nan   |     5     |  … |     10   |
| 2          |     Croatia |     Nan   |     1     |  … |     2    |
```

To tackle this issue, I decided to create a new dataframe which is the result of the concatenation of my original dataframe first and second columns and the other columns from the substract result.

```py
df_new = pd.concat([df[df.columns[:2]], df_copy[df_copy.columns[2:]]], axis=1)
```

I guess this is not the best way of doing this, is it ? Is there a way to have the desired result directly within the apply function (specifying the boundary condition or so) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert columns for not differences by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html),repalce `NaN`s columns by  [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last convert index to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Country')
df1 = df1.diff(1, axis=1).fillna(df1).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Country  Pop1  Pop2  Popn
0   Canada   0.0   2.0  48.0
1    China   0.0   5.0  70.0
2  Croatia   0.0   1.0  29.0
```

Comment: I guess I finally need to re-insert the missing `Pop1` column once it is done right ?

Comment: @Beinje - So need same like original values?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep the Pop1 column original values since this is useful data (time series). That's why I mentioned this "boundary" condition but maybe it wasn't that clear, I didn't know how to call that.